# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm trying to draw a chart using sql query editor using  a dynamic sql. I've built a part of the query in page 4 and I would like to use it into page 5.

In page 4 I built the query passing the parameters to a store procedure into a package in the database, receiving the part of the query. I need to use this way

This is the part of the structure query:

```
:P4_STRINGA_VIEW = from VIEW_OEE_MAC_MENSILE where V_COD_MACCHINA= 'REP03' and V_ANNO = '2020';
```

[image]

I've tryied to build the query witout the keyword "From" and this has been the result:
[image]

In a lot of examples I have seen about the dynamic sql, the most of these use the pl\sql code. The chart series options to getting data from database are sql query and PL\sql function body to return a sql query. I've tryied both, but I got alway the same error.

I've looked for examples, documentations about it, but I didn't find out a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

This example works in SQL*Plus; should in Apex too.

Function (you'd have just a function body; use `declare` instead of the first line I posted) that returns the `select` statement looks like this; I hardcoded `p4_stringa_view` as I don't know how you get it:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return varchar2 as
  2    p4_stringa_view varchar2(200) := 'from emp where deptno = 10';
  3    retval varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    return q'[select 'A' label, ename as V_OEE ]' || p4_stringa_view;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.
```

When executed, it returns

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select 'A' label, ename as V_OEE from emp where deptno = 10
```

Does the `select` statement itself work?

```
SQL> select 'A' label, ename as V_OEE from emp where deptno = 10  ;

L V_OEE
- ----------
A CLARK
A KING
A MILLER

SQL>
```

Yes, it does.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying your solution, but unfortunately I can't solve my problem. I've done a modify to your solution. I'm passing a parameter to the function. On sql developer I've added the function to the package and in apex I wrote in sql query editor this statement select 'A' label, apex_504.P5_READ_MULTIVALUES(:P4_STRINGA_VIEW) from dual;but I'm carrying on to have this error message:" ORA-04062: timestamp of package APEX_504; It has been changed. Initially the function returned a number, but alse in that case I got a error message.